# require_once action when browser reopened (Firefox?)

Tags: php, session, session-variables, session-cookies

I have a strange situation where when I re-open Firefox in the morning I get PHP errors on a page because session variables are used but not defined.

The browser is set to re-open tabs that were left open, and the PHP script that generates the page output begins with a require_once, the script being called ensuring that a session is started and setting session variables for the site.

During the day this works perfectly, however 1st thing in the morning when I re-open the browser and click on the tab, 2 "if" expressions that interrogate session variables throw errors because those session variables are not defined.

They are "unconditionally" defined in the require_once script, so I am assuming that if the page is reloaded by the browser, the script is assumed to already have been loaded and is not re-executed, however the session is not started.

I can't find any relevant articles that describe this problem, and since I can only "easily" test it once a day I thought it best to ask the gurus.

---

As requested, sample code added...

Top of main page

```
// Include Site Configuration And Global Functions
require_once 'thissite.php';

echo <<<HTML

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" />
<title>My Company - B2B Trade Stockist Sign In</title>
HTML;

include'head.php';

echo <<<HTML

</head>
<body>
<div class="container padding-10" style="text-align:center;">
    etc......

HTML;
```

Part of head.php which outputs the page head section

```
if ($_SESSION['ZEN_DESK'] == "on") {
    echo <<<HTML

<!-- Start of Zendesk Widget script -->
code removed
<!-- End of Zendesk Widget script -->

HTML;
}
```

Part of thissite.php which controls site settings

```
// Ensure session started
if (!session_id()) {
    session_start();
}

//  Zen Desk:
//      This allows you to control whether Zen Desk is active for a site.
$_SESSION['ZEN_DESK'] = "off";  //(on/off)
```

Under normal conditions during the day, when the page is loaded the session variable ZEN_DESK is defined. However, if the browser is closed with tabs left open at the end of the day, when the tab is clicked on in the morning I get a PHP error logged because ZEN_DESK is not defined.

Comment: Well, could you please post the code you're using? It's difficult to solve bugs by guessing

Comment: What condition you have kept to test the sessions? I mean, check that ``if isset($_SESSION) && $_SESSION !='')``

Comment: I "expect" that thissite.php will be executed every time the page is loaded, but it seems not to be if the tab is clicked on after the browser has been reloaded. Maybe even though the session has expired, the fact that the page is still open does not cause thissite.php to be executed again?

Answer (score 1):

A php session usually has a lifetime of 1440 secs (24 minutes). If the session does not get refreshed within that period of time (e.g. by loading/reloading a web page) all session variables will get deleted.

To see how long the lifetime is on your server look at the ini value `session.gc_maxlifetime`.

```
echo ini_get(session.gc_maxlifetime');
```

or

```
phpinfo();
```

And search for `session.gc_maxlifetime`.

Answer (score 1):

If you are using cookies to store the session variables, please check their lifetime. One way to overcome this situation is to refresh these cookies on pageload if the server side variables are not expired. The second way is to extend the lifetime on cookies on storing.

Comment: We are using PHP session variables in this case, but we do also use cookies.  I notice (with Firefox & Chrome at least) that if I have the browser set to open with tabs from last time, even though most of the cookies for our site are definesd as session cookies, they still remain set day after day.

Comment: You need to match the client with the server variables to harden the session security. Don't trust the cookies. But don't avoid using them. Maybe using a session token would help matching them. And once one of cookies or server sessions are expired, complete each other with the data remaining. Did you try accessing the "remaining" cookies from the server? It may give a hint for what the problem is.

Comment: I have tried checking the other session variables, some do seem to exist. As long as the page executes "thissite.php" when it loads, that ought to ensure there is a session and initialize the key variables.  Problem is when the tab is left open, the following morning when I open the browser it doesn't seem as if it does execute this, therefore the session is not checked. I will add an "echo" to "thissite.php" to see if it is executed or not.